# Run MySQL Openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift

I want to run a query agains mysql database stored in openshift.
As far I know there are two ways to do that:

1 - Make a port forward of the mysql pod and run the query pointing to that port from my local environment.

```
oc port-forward mysql-9-999aa 3306:3306
```

2 - run a rsh of the pod and execute mysql commands

```
oc rsh mysql-9-999aa
> mysql ...
```

However I want to ask if there is a way to run the query at once with exec command, something like:

```
oc exec mysql-9-999aa mysql --user=test --password=test myDatabase -e "SELECT * FROM test;"
```

I've tried that and it's not working. Anybody knows if it's possible to run a MySQL command with oc exec?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

`oc exec mysql-9-999aa -- bash -c "mysql --user=test --password=test myDatabase -e 'SELECT * FROM test;'"`